# How to replace all double quotes in a polars DataFrame?

Tags: python, string, quotes, python-polars

I have a csv-file, where some strings are enclosed in double quotes ("), others are not. I read the file into a polars DataFrame using python.

The table looks something like this:

```
┌────────────┬────────┬────────┬────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ address    ┆ id     ┆ lat    ┆ lon    ┆ name    ┆ state │ 
│ ---        ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---   │ 
│ str        ┆ str    ┆ f64    ┆ f64    ┆ str     ┆ str   │ 
╞════════════╪════════╪════════╪════════╪═════════╪═══════╡
```

I want to remove all double quotes. The problem only occurs in columns `address` and `name`.

For example some rows contain:

> "Brückenstraße 1012, 89542 Herbrechtingen"

others look like this:

> Brückenstraße 1012 89542 Herbrechtingen

and some others even have double quotes all over the place:

> "Grundschule ""J. W. von Goethe"" "

I have tried the following and various variations:
`df = df.with_columns(pl.col(["address"]).str.replace_all('"', ''))`
but with no success.
Some variations were putting an `r` before '"', escaping the double quotes and setting `literal=True`.

Edit: More reproducible data and code:
Data:

```
address,fax,full_time_school,id,lat,lon,name,official_id,phone,school_type,school_type_entity,state
"Rombacher Straße 30, 73430 Aalen",07361/9561-20,false,BW-75774,48.838598,10.08184,Schubart-Gymnasium Partnerschule für Europa,75774,07361/9561-0,Gymnasium (G8),Gymnasium,BW
Steinweg 8 91567 Herrieden,09825 4962,false,BY-6727,49.237197,10.497239,Volksschule Herrieden,6727,09825 219,Grund- und Hauptschule,Grund- und Hauptschule,BY
```

Code using `.ipynb` 3.12:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.read_csv("data.csv", has_header=True, columns=["address", "id", "lat", "lon", "name", "state"], encoding="utf8", separator=",",)
df = df.unique(subset=["id"])
df = df.drop_nulls(subset=["id", "lat", "lon"])
df = df.with_columns(pl.col(["address"]).str.replace_all('"', '',))
df = df.sort(by="id")
df.write_csv("data-clean.csv",)
```

Output in `data-clean.csv`:

```
address,id,lat,lon,name,state
"Rombacher Straße 30, 73430 Aalen",BW-75774,48.838598,10.08184,Schubart-Gymnasium Partnerschule für Europa,BW
Steinweg 8 91567 Herrieden,BY-6727,49.237197,10.497239,Volksschule Herrieden,BY
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show how it fails? What you have should work: `pl.select(pl.lit('foo""bar"baz"').str.replace_all('"', '')) # foobarbaz`

Comment: @jqurious it fails in the sense that all double quotes are still there after the operation. There is no error.

Comment: Can you provide your full input data frame and perhaps a slightly longer code snippet? The command you're using works for me.

Comment: Are you able to reduce it down to provide a runnable example?

Comment: Are you sure the double quotes are really in the data, not just the representation shown when you print them?

Comment: @jqurious I made an edit to the post

Comment: @kevin41 I provided an example in the post

Comment: The only quotes in the input file are the ones around a field that has an embedded comma. Those quotes won't be put into the value, they're just used to prevent the comma from being a field separator. So there's nothing to replace.